# Android app (not activity) visibility change event

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have developed one small Android app for testing purpose. Now I need to know that how many users are online/active on my app. means any user minimize my app and go to android home, then I want notification/event and when he/she come again on my app, then also it should notify/event. Is it possible?

Comment: You must used flurry

Comment: @lopez.mikhael, can you explain me? I can't understand what you said. I have checked flurry.com. But it is not my solution. I want just simple event, when my app is appear in-front of user and another event when user switch from my app.

Comment: With flurry you can get analytics about your users app and send push notifications. I think It responds to your problem.

Comment: @lopez.mikhael, I have check what you suggest. but this is not a solution for my work. Is their any way to do ourself in Android?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no event that will tell you what you need.
But there are some workarounds.

Maybe try with this one: http://vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.in/2013/05/android-solution-to-detect-when-android.html
or this one http://www.vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.com/2014/02/android-solution-to-detect-when-android.html

Answer (score -1):

take a look at the livecircle http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

> When the system calls onPause() for your activity, it technically means your activity is still partially visible, but most often is an indication that the user is leaving the activity and it will soon enter the Stopped state
>
> When the user resumes your activity from the Paused state, the system calls the onResume() method.

Comment: I want just simple event, when my app is appear in-front of user and another event when user switch from my app. can you please mention/show me any example?

Comment: There is a demo on the Link I posted

Comment: The question explicitly asks for the app events but the answer is about activity events